# Determine type of a List?

Tags: c#, list

In c#, can we determine what type a List is holding before doing something else? Example:

```
List<int> listing = new List<int>();

if(listing is int)
{
    // if List use <int> type, do this...
}
else if(listing is string)
{
    // if List use <string> type, do this...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method.

Like:

```
Type[] types = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
if (types.Length == 1 && types[0] == typeof(int))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if(listing is List<int>) ...
```

Comment: +1 Although both answers do provide a solution to the question asked, I believe this to be the better solution for this specific question.  Although there are very valid uses for the `Type.GetGenericArguments()` method, this usage just introduces an unnecessary level of reflection (and then typeof still must be used to inspect the generic type parameter) since the variable is known to be a List<T>.  This answer provides a more efficient solution requiring less code.

Answer (score 1):

When coding in an object oriented language as c# we generally prefer using polymorphism rather than using conditionals on the runtime type. Try something like this next time and see if you like it!

```
interface IMyDoer
{
    void DoThis();
}

class MyIntDoer: IMyDoer
{
    private readonly List<int> _list;
    public MyIntClass(List<int> list) { _list = list; } 
    public void DoThis() { // Do this... }
}
class MyStringDoer: IMyDoer
{
    private readonly List<string> _list;
    public MyIntClass(List<string> list) { _list = list; } 
    public void DoThis() { // Do this... }
}
```

Call like this:

```
doer.DoThis(); // Will automatically call the right method
//depending on the runtime type of 'doer'!
```

The code becomes shorter and cleaner and you don't have to have a djungle with if statements.

This way of arranging the code (or factoring) you are free to change the internal structure of the code without breaking it. If you use conditional you will find that the code easily breaks when for example fixing an unrelated problem. This is a very valuable property of the code. Hope you find this helpful!