# How to get typeof(List<>) from typeof(List<T>) by removing generic argument

Tags: c#, generics

I have `typeof(List<T>)` as a Type object, but I need the `typeof(List<>)` from which I can use `MakeGenericType()` to retrieve a type object for List, is it possible?

**Update:** Guys, thx. This seems a trivial question. But anyway, I upvoted everyone and accepted the first answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037754/determine-type-of-a-list
Have you watched this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I undestand your problem correctly, you have a generic type (`List<int>`) and another type (lets say `long`) and you want to make a `List<long>`. That can be done like this:

```
Type startType = listInt.GetType();   // List<int>
Type genericType = startType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()  //List<T>
Type targetType = genericType.MakeGenericType(secondType) // List<long>
```

However, if the types you are working with are indeed lists, it might be clearer if you actually used:

```
Type targetType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(secondType) // List<long>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to achieve something like the below?

```
var list = new List<int>();
Type intListType = list.GetType();
Type genericListType = intListType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
Type objectListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(typeof(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx

Example:

```
var t = typeof(List<string>);
var t2 = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

And then could do this:

```
var t = typeof(List<>);
var t2 = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
```